# Added product will not appear in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In Magento i added one category. 
After that I added product for that category. 
But unfortunatly thae product is not getting displayed

Can any one tell me any step is there i am missing out ?

Comment: add the error msg?

Comment: Check Quantity in Inventory section, also check In stock

Comment: how to check error msg ? 

Inventory Quantity is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options in Magento.

Like We need to set the Product status to Enable, and visibility to Catalog, Search. In the inventory section set the stock availability option to "In Stock".

The Steps to do this are:

1.Go to the product section in Catalog->Product->General Option

-> Check Status and visibility there and set the option according to you.

2. Go in inventory section.

   -> Check the Stock Availability option there. If it's out of stock then set it to "In Stock".
3. Category Section

   -> Make sure you have selected the right category.

After that, you are good to Go with your product.

Good Luck!

Comment: Inventory was 0. I changed it as a no 2.another changes all right.  But now also not appear. 
What is need to do. a

Comment: Please check this youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqEA7Wcyxe4 it will help you in detail.

Comment: This your answer is ok. but not showing my product. I dont know why. I think i have to create menu also. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Check **stock** and also check whether it is enabled or not. If it doesn't show yet, then perform reindexing by following method:

in case of magento2, run:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

in case of magento1, it can be done from admin panel.

after this clear cache and check.

hope, this will work.

Comment: I'm using magento 1.9. Then how to do it? I'm doing this things in localhost.

Comment: then log into admin panel, navigate to *System -> Index Management*  and reindex. it must help.